# is ros client c++ code thread safe?

Tags: ros, c++, threads

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I initialize and run the ros C++ client code in it's own thread?

I'm thinking of creating a thread, and in the thread initializing ROS, then having my main loop run there.

I can't see why not, but I thought I'd ask before venturing there.  If there is any general guidance on using threads and ros, that would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9413/is-ros-client-c++-code-thread-safe?/) by [SeanPayne](https://answers.ros.org/users/276/seanpayne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roscpp is threadsafe.  There is a summary of the threading model in the [roscpp overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview) on the [Callbacks and Spinning](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) page.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4